# Having trouble plotting a log-log plot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, physics

Hey so I'm trying to plot variables like age against its frequency, for a rotating body. I am given the period and period derivative aswell as their associated errors. Since frequency is related to period by:

```
f = 1/T
```

where frequency is f and period is T

then,

```
df = - (1/(T^2)) * dT
```

where dT and dF are the derivatives of period and frequency

but when it comes to plotting the log of this I can't do it in python as it doesn't accept negative values for a loglog plot.

I've tried a work around of using only absolute values but then I only get half the errors when plotting error bars. Is there a way to make python plot both the negative and positive error bars? The frequency derivative itself is a negative quantity.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, log(x) cannot be negative because `log(x) = y` <=> `10^y = x`.

**Is 10^y ever going to be -5?**

Unfortunately it is impossible to make `10^y<=0` because as `y` becomes -infinity, `x` approaches 1/infinity; `x` approaches, but never passes 0.

**Is it possible to plot log(x), where x is negative?**

One simple solution to your problem however, is to take the absolute value of `df`. By doing this, negative numbers become positive. The only downside is that after you've transformed the data this way, you will need to undo the transformation. If the number was negative (and turned positive due to `abs(df)`), then you must multiply it by -1 afterwards.

You may need to define your own absolute value function that records any values it needs to make positive:

```
changeList = []

def absRecordChanges(value):
    if value < 0 :
        value = value * -1
        changeList.append(value)
    return value
```

There are other ways to solve the problem, but they are all centred around transforming your data to meet the conditions of a log tranformation (x > 0), and having the data you changed recorded so you can change it back afterward (before you plot it).

*EDIT:*
While fiddling around in desmos, I was able to plot `log(x)` where `x` is any integer. I used a piecewise function to do this: `{x<0:-log(abs(x)),log (x)}`.

```
def piecewiseLog(x)
    If x <= 0 :
        return -log(abs(x))
    else :
        return log(x)
```

As I'm not familiar with matlab syntax, this link has an alternative solution: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/31566-display-negative-values-on-logarithmic-graph